# My object is not displaying editable data grid combo-box value

Tags: jquery, json, combobox, jquery-easyui

I am trying to display a json object in editable data grid but unable to disply the key value (it displaying  [object Object] .
So far what I tried

```
columns:[[
                {field:'id',title:'S.No',width:60,hidden:true},
                 {field:'tblLookUpList',title:'Dependent Lookup Value',value:'lookUpValue',width:150,sortable:true,align:'left',
                      editor:{
                         type:'combobox',
                         options:{
                            url:'${request.getContextPath()}/tblLookUp/getTblLookUp',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            valueField:'id',
                            textField:'lookUpValue',
                            displayField:'lookUpValue',
                            panelHeight:'auto',
                            editable:false
                         }   
                      }
                   },
                {field:'conditionalLookUpValue',value:'conditionalDisplayValue',title:'Lookup value',width:80,align:'right',editor:{type:'text',options:{required:true}}},
                {field:'conditionalDisplayValue',title:'Display Value',width:80,align:'right',editor:{type:'text',options:{required:true}}},
                {field:'activeStatus',title:'Active',width:50,align:'center',
                    editor:{
                        type:'checkbox',
                        options:{
                            on: 'A',
                            off: ''
                        }
                    }
                },
```

here the `tblLookUpList`(mentioned in 3rd line) field is object type,Here i how to differentiate that.

And Present O/p :-

[Present Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLQN9.png)

But here instead of displaying value its displaying like this `[object Object]`

Comment: You should provide your function `getTblLookUp` to help others trace your problem...but it's maybe about your return value from that function